# Can't send mail using mail() PHP - 555 sorry, too many emails

Tags: apache-2.2, email-server, email

Since this morning, I can't send mail from my Ubuntu server. I use PHP and Msmtp, I looked at the Apache logs, and found:

```
msmtp: authentication failed (method PLAIN)
msmtp: server message: 555 sorry, too many emails (#5.7.1)
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/apache2/.msmtprc)
```

I have not touched anything, how can I fix this concern?

Comment: Where are you relaying to?

Comment: I was relaying on my domain (by OVH). I took a look to my manager, but no limit was visible. I just passed now to Postfix and it seems to be ok. Wait and see for now ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your php, but in your outgoing mail system. You sent probably too many mails to a server and they now don't allow this for you.

Comment: In addition, if you didn't expect your php application to send a large amount of emails, you should check if there are issues with it e.g. a rogue script has been sending spam, spambots spamming a webform you may have etc etc